# Gmail REST API Users.messages.attachments: get - not returning filename

Tags: rest, get, gmail, attachment, gmail-api

I need to be able to collect multipple attachments in any email body. My testcase is based on multipart/mixed formatted email. I was able to get the filename correctly for a **single attachment**. The problem can easily be seen when including a `console.log('Filename' + part.filename)` inside the callback. It will always remain empty. It seems like the array - parts is always "stuck" on the last in the index, which in my case will give me an empty part.filename and a wrong part.mimeType.

I have tried all sorts of workarounds including pushing and pop'ing the correct filename but this does not work because the attachments are returned in a random sequence..

I belive this is an error, and I hope this can be recognized as an Error as I really need to have this fixed.

EDIT: Additional information after some more investigation:
 1. The request.execute(function( attachment).. is only runnning once -
    after the for..loop has finished, even if there is multipple
    attachments. BUT It will return the correct attachments - also
    multipple, in a random sequence.

2. The attachment object returned from request.execute(function(
   attachment) will NEVER contain an attachmentId, only the raw data
   and size.
3. The size returned from attachment object request.execute(function(
   attachment) is not the same size as reported by var parts =
   message.payload.parts; which makes it impossible to be used for correlating.
4. The request.execute(function(attachment) will only use the last data
   from the var parts = message.payload.parts; which is not related to
   the attachment.

function getAttachments(userId, message, callback) {
var parts = message.payload.parts;

```
for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
part = parts[i];
if (part.filename && part.filename.length > 0){
    var attachId = part.body.attachmentId;
    myfilename.push( part.filename )
    var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.attachments.get({
    'id': attachId,
    'messageId': message.id,
    'userId': userId
    }); 

request.execute(function( attachment) {

// PROBLEM: part.filename and part.mimeType is empty or wrong.            
callback( **part.filename**, part.mimeType, attachment );
});
}
}
```

}

```
function callback( name, mime, att ) {
// PROBLEM: empty name, and wrong mime 
console.log( 'Filnavn: ' + name );
if (name == '') {
 name = myfilename.pop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the file context so that when callback is made, it knows the original filename and mimetype as follows:

```
function getAttachments(userId, message, callback) {
  var parts = message.payload.parts;
  var attachments = [];//The attachments cache
  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    part = parts[i];
    if (part.filename && part.filename.length > 0) {
        var attachId = part.body.attachmentId;
        myfilename.push(part.filename);
        console.log('attachId=' + attachId);
        console.log('MessageID=' + message.id);
        console.log('UserID=' + userId);
        var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.attachments.get({
            'id': attachId,
            'messageId': message.id,
            'userId': userId
        });
        attachments[attachId] = {filename: part.filename, mimeType:part.mimeType};
        request.execute(function (attachment) {
        // PROBLEM: part.filename and part.mimeType is empty or wrong.            
            var file = attachments[attachment.attachmentId];
            callback(file.filename, file.mimeType, attachment);
        });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Furhan Shabir, thanks for your comment, but I cannot see the whole picture you are drawing here! If the data from part.filename is not existing from the callback, I do not understand how recursion would help me out? Can you give me an example please?

Comment: If you are receiving messages from gmail API using get() with format='full' then you must be receiving the part. However the part may be be of type 'multipart/mixed' or 'multipart/alternative' suggesting that it itself contains parts of different mime types. This is where recursion comes into play.

Comment: Hi @Furhan Shabir - Just to clarify: I do get both the part.filename and the message. I just cant get them in the same callback. No way to correlate the **att** and **name** as shown in the callback.

Comment: @petrusjak You need to save the context so that when callback() is called, it has the appropriate params. Modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: So I follow your analogy and tried your code, but this only re-assured me that the problem is connected to the use of **request.execute(function( attachment)** The fact is that the attachment object returned do not have any attachId, so it is impossible to correlate with the ID fetched earlier. The request.execute is also executed only once when the other for loop is finished - SO - any more ideas would be great!

Comment: I am getting issue on this line gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.attachments, gmail is not defined

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you have this problem solved. I am facing the same issue. 
While I look at the Google [ApI Gmail Attachment Play ground](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments/get) 
Even though I have those fields:attachmentId,data,size. The response just doesn't give the attachmentId. I guess we probably shouldn't use the bathQuery approach.

Comment: I am getting issue on this line gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.attachments, gmail is not defined